# How to point a text files with bulk phone number on asterisk callfile

Tags: asterisk

I am looking for a solution about asterisk call file. can any one please give me a clear example that how can i use bulk phone number on asterisk call file, want to put all numbers in a text file and add that text file to call file extension configuration so the call file can pull the text file and make call too all numbers. same i want to do for caller id, that i can be use more then 1 caller id.

Rezan Khan

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer : you can't

Asterisk is pbx, it not designed to do massive calling.

Use dialler cores like vicidial.org

Comment: Oh! Really ? then how the vicidial work? they also using asterisk, hope you know about asterisk spool which is pbx_spool.so module which generate automatic outgoing calls. and all the auto dialer  is just a php or java frameworks which manager asterisk via browser.

Comment: Vicidial work via ami Originate. One-by-one. Vicidial do planning itself. There is no point in doing dialler core yourself if you are not expert in asterisk. Task is not trivial and have alot of roadblocks along the way.